# restore mysql database from an old mysql folder

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, innodb

i want to restore one database from my old mysql folder,

i copied mysql/data folder from old installation into my current mysql folder, yet its not starting up any more.

when i check the error_log file i see

```
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-05-04 11:01:24 1d5c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1689664 and 1689664 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 3461183 in the ib_logfiles!
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-05-04 11:01:24 5344 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace database/settings uses space ID: 146 at filepath: .\database\settings.ibd. Cannot open tablespace elegant/encounter_dr which uses space ID: 146 at filepath: .\elegant\encounter_dr.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\elegant\encounter_dr.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

i'm not sure what exactly is the problem, i copied the folder as is.. may be its a different mysql version (2years old backup) but i'm sure everthing is there !.

is there anyother way to restore database from data folder ?

I saw in log file that elegant db is causing the problem, since i dont even need it i deleted the hole folder. now mysql starts but it show only tables, and when ever i try to use this table it say Table doesnot exists

i check log now there is a new errors

```
2014-05-04 11:03:41 7828 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table z125/inventory_items from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2014-05-04 11:03:41 7828 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table z125/inventory_transactions from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
```

Comment: you have sqldump as `fomefile.sql` ?

Comment: nop, i copied whole folder of mysql as a backup, didnt dump database

Comment: Open my.ini and add `innodb_force_recovery = 1` in `[mysqld]` section. Restart mysql.

Comment: did so, the server started but could not display table data. it shows tables in phpmyadmin but when i click on table it send message "table doesnot exists"